# How do you get weekdays array for a selected locale using moment.js without changing its global localization?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What I'm currently doing is:

```
moment.locale(locale)
moment.weekdays(true)
```

But `moment.locale(locale)` changes the locale of the whole moment library and I only want to get a list of weekdays in a different locale without changing it.

I tried using

```
moment.localeData(locale).weekdays()
```

but you can't pass `true` to "weekdays" so the result doesn't sort items. For example:

```
moment.locale('en-us')
moment.weekdays(true) // ["Sunday", "Monday", ...

moment.locale('en-gb')
moment.weekdays(true) // ["Monday", "Tuesday", ...
```

But

```
moment.localeData('en-us').weekdays() // ["Sunday", "Monday", ...

moment.localeData('en-gb').weekdays() // ["Sunday", "Monday", ...
```

And there is no

```
moment.localeData('en-gb').weekdays(true)
```

Edit:
Looks like they have an open issue about it, so please suggest your best hacks meanwhile:
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4066

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `weekday` function is locale-aware, so

```
const weekdays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(dow => moment().locale('en-gb').weekday(dow).format('dddd'))
```

will give you array `['Sunday', 'Monday', ...]` for `en-us`, but `['Monday', 'Tuesday', ...]` for `en-gb`.